# How can I get the host name and query that has been executed on the slave postgres database that caused the system into the memory crashed

Tags: postgresql, out-of-memory, shared-memory, database-restore, postgres-9.4

My slave database has undergone the memory crash(Out of memory) and in recovery stage.
I want to know the query that causes this issue.

I have checked logs I get one query just before the system goes into the recovery mode;But I want to confirm it.

I am using postgres 9.4

If any one has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `log_min_error_statement` to `error` (the default) or lower, you will get the statement that caused the out-of-memory error in the database log.

But I assume that you got hit by the Linux OOM killer, that would cause a PostgreSQL process to be killed with signal 9, whereupon the database goes into recovery mode.

The correct solution here is to disable memory overcommit by setting `vm.overcommit_ratio` to 2 in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and activate the setting with `sysctl -p` (you should then also tune `vm.overcommit_ratio` correctly).

Then you will get an error rather than a killed process, which is easier to debug.

Comment: If a process is killed with signal 9 by OOM;then queries are also not logged.At the same time i have one long query in my logs just before the database has gone in recovery mode.Should I consider that query as cuprit or slow query?

Comment: Depends. If it is logged because of `log_min_duration_statement`, no (because it is logged after it is done). If it is logged because of `log_statement`, perhaps. I would still disable the OOM killer.